# SSH password refused from outside lan

Tags: ssh, login, internet, password

SSH is not accepting my correct unix password for the user I am trying to connect to via ssh from outside of my home network. The SSH server answers, takes my password input three times, then says authentication failed(publickey, password). This happens no matter what user I try to login as. sshd_config is configured to accept passwords, permit root login, and accept public keys. I can find no answer to this particular problem with google or ask ubuntu. All I can find says to edit sshd_config to allow passwords, but it doesn't change the behavior. router is set to forward port 22 to the correct computer. I honestly don't know what to do here.

Comment: did you reboot/restart the sshd service after changing settings?

Comment: What shows up in `/var/log/auth.log` after a login attempt?

Comment: *"permit root login"* so, are you actually trying to login as root?